# Tkinker module for Python 2.7

Tags: python, tkinter

I have Python 2.7 and windows vista.

When I run following code:

```
`from Tkinker import  *`
```

It will give this error:

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Button", line 5, in <module>
    from Tkinker import  *
ImportError: No module named Tkinker
```

So please help me about how to install Tkinker module where to copy source code of Tkinker module  ?

Comment: Have you googled *Tkinker*?

Comment: Even the tagging here would've shown the problem  ;)

Answer (score 3):

You misspelled the module name. It's `Tkinter` not `Tkinker`